# Find $\int_c \bar z$ along the parabola $y=x^2$ from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I know $\bar z=x-iy$
So we have $$\int_c x-iy \,dz$$ when split up gives us $$\int^1_0 x \, dx-i\int^1_0 x^2 \cdot 2x \, dx$$
and then I integrate as usual as usual and I get the result $$\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{1}{2}$$
This is wrong as the answer is $$1+\frac{i}{3}$$
How do I get this answer?

Comment: when parametrizing your curve by $x+ix^2$ from $0$ to $1,$ the derivative is $1+2ix$ so your integral should be $\int_{0}^{1} (x-ix^2)(1+2ix) \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: I guess if you're familiar with line integrals, the concept is very similar. You start by parametrizing the contour and start substituting things in.

Comment: @mathnewbie why is it $x+ix^2$ ? Should it not be $x-ix^2$ because we are looking at $\bar z$ and not Z?

Comment: @Aljabra, this is just the parametrization of the contour. When you put that in your function $f(z) = \overline{z}$, it becomes $x-ix^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize the curve as $x=t$, $y=t^2$.  Then, $dz=(1+i2t)dt$  and

$$\int_C \bar z\,dz=\int_0^1(t-it^2)\,(1+i2t)dt=\int_0^1(t+2t^3)\,dt+i\int_0^1t^2\,dt=1+i\frac13$$

Comment: @ Dr.MV should it not be $dz=(1-i2t)dt$?

Comment: @aljabra While the integrand is $\bar z$, the differential is $dz\ne d\bar z$.  So, the answer is correct.